# Persistent Cart When Switching Between Users React

Tags: reactjs, cookies, cart

I'm storing my users carts in a cookie with an expiration date of 72 hours. My problem right now is that if someone is logged into one account, and then logs into another account, the cart will persist since its cookie based.

It's an easy solution to just remove the cart cookie if someone logs out, but then it doesn't seem easy to recover the cart once its been destroyed. Obviously I could store all of the cart information in a database, but it just seems relatively unsafe compared to storing it in localStorage or a cookie.

Is storing multiple carts in multiple cookies a viable strategy?

How do people make user-persistent carts with cookies?

Comment: A server-side database is far more reliable than client-side cookies/storage

Answer (score 0):

use the user id in the cookie name i.e., `cart_321`, that way you can always check if the cookie exist for the logged user.